# solaris 11.4 virtual machine not connecting to the internet?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox, solaris

I set up a virtual machine from **Oracle Solaris 11.4 VirtualBox Template (x86)**. 
When configuring I set up it as no network and after starting the virtual machine I assigned a static ip addresss which is in the same range of the host ip. After that I can ping with each other. But I cant access the internet from the virtual machine. How to fix this.

here is my host IP

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
       Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8d41:b6a5:233f:a8c9%13
       IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.91
       Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
       Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
```

I connected the host to the internet via mobile phone WiFi hotspot.

In my virtual box I put following network setting to this virtual machine.

[image]

In the virtual machine terminal I entered following commands,

```
# dladm show-link
LINK     CLASS     MTU     STATE     OVER
net0     phys      1500    unknown        --       --


# ipadm create-ip net0
# ipadm create-addr -a 192.168.43.114/24 net0
net0/v4
```

[image]

I can ping with host to VM and Vm to host. But I cant connect to the internet from VM . What is the reason for that? I want to connect to the internet from the vm and it should hold a static ip address. is it possible to do?

Comment: What is your host OS?  Can you access the internet from other VMs?

Comment: I'm haven't used VirtualBox in a while. Any idea what the "Invalid settings detected" warning in your screenshot is about?